# My discord code is not working! It only shows error when i run the program

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Here is the code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

@bot.command()
async def sayhi(ctx, name):
    await ctx.send(f"Hi {name}!")


bot.run("TOKEN")
```

And here is the error what im getting:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'discord.ext'; 'discord' is not a package
```

But i all ready did pip install discord command in cmd!

Comment: Is your script itself named `discord.py`?

Comment: yes its named discord.py

Comment: Then that's the problem.  Your script is importing _itself_, because it has the same name as the module, and imports always look in the current directory first.  Name your script something else.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me, that you named your file were you are working in discord.py.
This Filename is already reserved for the package you are importing. If you now name your working file to the name of a file, which is reserved by a package, it will try to import iteself which obviusly throw you a errorcode. a simple solution is to rename the file to something else than discord.py

Answer (score 0):

try this

```py
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

@bot.command()
async def sayhi(ctx, member):
    await ctx.send(f"Hi {member.mention}!")


bot.run("TOKEN")
```

make sure you do
pip install discord.py
into you console